# Writing a function without the class in start (Like "Raylib.InitWindow()" to "InitWindow()" only)

Tags: c#, raylib

I started using raylibCS with C# in VS.

To use raylib's functions, you need to write `Raylib.` before the function name, so it would look like this:

```
Raylib.InitWindow(640, 480, "game");
```

This is tiring and unproductive (in my pov), so is there a way I could just use the function without the class name on the start, like `InitWindow(640, 480, "game");`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless a method is a member of the current type, you must qualify it when calling it (a qualifying `this` is implied if you don't provide it). This `InitWindow` method is a presumably a `static` member of the `RayLib` class, so you have no choice but to qualify the method name. The one thing you can do is alias the type with a `using` statement. You could add this with your namespace imports at the top of the file:

```cs
using rl = RayLib;
```

and you can then call:

```cs
rl.InitWindow(640, 480, "game");
```

Note that you may need to qualify `RayLib` with a namespace in that import.

Having said that, is this really a problem? If you start typing `RayLib` then Intellisense will probably help you before you finish, so you then just hit the dot and probably type one or two letters of the method name before Intellisense pipes up again. If you were to just start typing the method name then you'd likely have to type more characters to get an Intellisense match so you're saving yourself a couple of keystrokes at most, really.